# How to change Xamarin.Forms Tab Bar height (iOS)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to change the height of a Tab Bar in Xamarin.Forms (iOS)? Is it possible with TabbedRenderer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah this is possible to modify from a `CustomRenderer`.

You will need to subclass the `TabbedPage` in the Forms project and use this class to export the render.

Then in the CustomRenderer override the `ViewWillLayoutSubviews` method. Something like:

```
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
    // Modify this variable with the height you desire.
    private readonly float tabBarHeight = 55f;

    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

        TabBar.Frame = new CGRect(TabBar.Frame.X, TabBar.Frame.Y + (TabBar.Frame.Height - tabBarHeight), TabBar.Frame.Width, tabBarHeight);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Sorry to revive this old thread, but this approach seems to not be working anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, it seems like in the current version (for me it's XF 4.4) this has to be done in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.